# Подскажите идею ,как реализовать?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Даны целые p и q .Вивести на экран все делители числа q , взаимно простые с p.

Comment: Вам стоит скопировать текст вашего вопроса и загуглить это слово в слово. Уверяю вас, ответы на это есть. А поскольку в заголовке темы вы указали, что вам нужна идея реализации, вам не должно мешать, что ответы на на языке Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Алгоритм таков:

1. Ищем все делители p
2. Ищем все делители q
3. Выбираем делитель числа p
4. Ищем его делители
5. Если хоть один делитель (кроме 1) совпадает, то вычеркиваем делитель
6. Повторяем пункты 3-5 пока не все делители числа p исследованы